# How to associate elements in different columns according to string position

Tags: r

I have a series of timepoints and associated values stored in two seperate columns as follows:

structure(list(frucTimePoint = c("Time Point (min)\a_0\a_20\a_40\a_60\a_80\a_100\a_120\a_140\a_160\a_180\a_", 
"Time Point (min)\a_0\a_20\a_40\a_60\a_80\a_100\a_120\a_140\a_160\a_180\a_"
), frucH2 = c("H2\r_19\a_5\a_7\a_15\a_21\a_13\a_17\a_12\a_10\a_8\a_", 
"H2\r_6\a_6\a_11\a_5\a_1\a_2\a_1\a_1\a_2\a_0\a_")), .Names = c("frucTimePoint", 
"frucH2"), row.names = 3:4, class = "data.frame")

I would like to associate each time point with the value so that I end up with a timepoint:association in its own column as follows

```
frucH2_0 frucH2_20 frucH2_40 frucH2_60 etc.
19       5        7          15

 6         6       11         5
```

So I thought the initial part would involve splitting the string for both TimePoint and frucH2 according to a delimiter and then somehow associating each named column for TimePoint with a named column for the frucH2 value I have tried to use strsplit to do this:

`cSplit(dataBT,frucH2,"|")` as well as `separate` from `tidyr`in order to at least split according to a delimiter but I can't even get this part to work

Is there a more succinct way to do this?
Note the timepoints that values are measured at can differ.

Comment: Can you `dput` the data? Because the structure will matter, and that table has many spaces which makes reading it in hard.

Comment: Agh.  Computer has just died. Will do as soon as I have access again

Comment: @Axeman I now dputted the data

Comment: You might want to check that `dput`, because it looks nothing like your original example. You only have 2 columns now? With NA's?

Comment: Yes I have changed it to simplify the question data and so that it fits the desired out. All I did was remove the column that wasn't relevant so I think the current dput is relevant

Comment: that dput still looks weird to me, still bears little resemblance to the question.

Comment: The NAs are just empty rows so the output shouldn't include them. The dput is accurate. Could you explain which bit is inaccurate with the output and I will correct. However intended the output is accurate I think

Comment: Ok so just in case I've missed something I have done a further dput so hopefully more straightforward